# How to push an item to an array in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, multidimensional-array

I'm new in Kotlin, and got this case for my project..
I have this example of array :

```
items: [
        {name: "item A", quantity: "9"},
        {name: "item B", quantity: "2"},
        {name: "item C", quantity: "4"},
]
```

and i have an object that i want to add to items[ ]

```
new_object: {name: "item AA", quantity: "4"}
```

Can anyone help me, how to do it in Kotlin...?
Thank you before..

Comment: Please provide the Kotlin code of your existing data structures. You only provided some JSON-ish data structure. Generally speaking, arrays in Kotlin can't change their size, so you can't add items to them. You have to use list instead of array or create a new array by simply adding to the existing one, e.g.: `arrayOf(1, 2, 3) + 4`.

Comment: +1 to what @broot said. Also, the JSON in the question does not represent a multidimensional array. It's just an array of complex objects

Comment: Agreed. I have submitted an edit for the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use both `MutableList` and `ArrayList` for this case.

First of all, you will need to define the structure for your items

```kotlin
data class Item(
    val name: String,
    val quantity: String
)
```

Then you initialize the list

```kotlin
val items = mutableListOf(
    Item("Item A", "1"),
    Item("Item B", "2"),
    Item("Item C", "3"),
)

// Or

val items = arrayListOf(
    Item("Item A", "1"),
    Item("Item B", "2"),
    Item("Item C", "3"),
)
```

And finally, when you want to append your item to the array you can do it like this

```kotlin
val newItem = Item("Item D", "4")
items.add(newItem)
```

Complete code will look like this:

```kotlin
data class Item(
    val name: String,
    val quantity: String
)

val items = mutableListOf(
    Item("Item A", "1"),
    Item("Item B", "2"),
    Item("Item C", "3"),
)

val newItem = Item("Item D", "4")
items.add(newItem)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is so usefull.
One question, how do i get only name value or quantity value from Item[ ] ?

Comment: You are very welcome! Here is a [code snippet](https://pastebin.com/VzKGMXA5) to answer your question. I used `map` for this particular example but the idea is the same(`item.quantity`, etc.) It is simple but will do the job :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Kotlin Collection ArrayList.
example

```
val list = ArrayList<String>()
list.add("Sample")
```

Likewise, you can replace String with your object. The solution for your code will be something like this

```
class User(var name:String,var quantity:String)

fun initList(){
    val list = arrayListOf<User>(
               User("Item A","9"),
               User("Item B","2"),
               User("Item C","4")
      )

list.add(User("Item AA",4))}
```

Comment: Note: it's usually more idiomatic to use `mutableListOf` instead of `arrayListOf` unless you really absolutely need an actual `ArrayList`. If it's an implementation detail, it's better to stick to the more general `mutableListOf`

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have a Array< String> arrayData . You can convert it to a Arraylist and then add the necessary strings and then again convert it to Array

```
 val location= ArrayList<String>()
                        for(item in arrayData){
                            location.add(item)
                        }
                        location.add("Private Mileage")
                        location.add("Conference)

                        val towns: Array<String> = location.toTypedArray<String>()
```